# Как удалить компоненты/расширения Visual Studio 2017 for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio

При установке Visual Studio программа спрашивает какие компоненты я еще хочу установить (типа разработка для android, unity и все такое). Если выбрал некоторые пункты ,а теперь они мне не нужны, то как удалить эти части?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустить инсталлятор, убрать галочки и нажать примирить.

Не думаю, что удаление компонентов стоит делать, ведь это не повлияет на производительность и т.д.

Если используете Mac, то есть описание на сайте ms
    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall

Comment: Visual Studio версии для Mac и там нет инсталятора как в Windows. Есть другие варианты как удалить?

Comment: Есть, добавил ссылку в ответ. Также можно поискать в англоязычном интернете